# What is a Variadic Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Variadic Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Variadic Words™ | Not Variadic Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| DAYDREAM | NIGHTMARE |
| LIABLE | RESPONSIBLE |
| ANDROID | APPLE |
| INDIAN | ATLANTIC |
| BRAINSTORM | THINK |
| STYMIE | HINDER |
| PRECIOUSLY | VALUABLY |
| CENTRIOLE | VACUOLE |
| HEADSTOCK | FRETBOARD |
| BASSOON | HARPSICHORD |
| PENGUIN | HIPPOPOTAMUS |
| FARBAUTI | SUTTUNGR |
| EXCEEDING | SURPASSING |
| STREAKING | SMUDGING |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Variadic Words™,Not Variadic Words™
DAYDREAM,NIGHTMARE
LIABLE,RESPONSIBLE
ANDROID,APPLE
INDIAN,ATLANTIC
BRAINSTORM,THINK
STYMIE,HINDER
PRECIOUSLY,VALUABLY
CENTRIOLE,VACUOLE
HEADSTOCK,FRETBOARD
BASSOON,HARPSICHORD
PENGUIN,HIPPOPOTAMUS
FARBAUTI,SUTTUNGR
EXCEEDING,SURPASSING
STREAKING,SMUDGING
```

Because this seems to be more difficult than expected:

Hint:

> Consider vowels vs. consonants

Comment: Just to help out, variadic in computer science refers to functions that take a variable (e.g. not explicitly restrictive, upto technically infinite) number of arguments.

Comment: If we suggest a rule that fits the current set of words but is incorrect by your solution, will you give us another pair of words that disproves the proposed solution?

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 Post it as an answer. Also keep in mind the name of the puzzle is a hint (either way, is like to see your answer, even if it doesn't work with the name).

Comment: I don't have a concise answer yet. I'm just curious if you'll just say "No that's incorrect," or if you'd be willing to provide additional information to disprove a given answer and guarantee only one solution (or at least a simpler solution) to the puzzle.

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 If that comes up, I will provide more cases.

Comment: The words in the (image) table here are mixed-case (capital at start, then lowercase) whereas the words in the CSV are all uppercase. I know that sometimes these puzzles turn on the shapes of letters; erdekhayser, would you care to state (or deny) explicitly that the upper/lower distinction makes no difference to whether something is a Variadic Word (tm) ?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Upper/lowercase has no meaning in this puzzle.

Comment: I have a pattern in mind(of course this is just one step); I want to ask if 'mpermst' is a word would it be NOT Variadic ?(sorry I just put random letters according to pattern)

Comment: @smriti That word would be Variadic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> A Variadic Word is one where no consecutive group of vowels has the same number of characters, and no consecutive group of consonants has the same number of characters.
>
>
>  For instance: "Brainstorm" can be separated into 
> BR AI NST O RM, 
> then
>  Vowels:(AI, O) and  Consonants:(BR, NST, RM) 
>  This gives counts of 
> Vowels:(2,1) and Consonants(2,3,2). 
>  Since no consecutive number repeats, it is Variadic.

More Examples:

Variadic:

> LIABLE   V:(2,1)  C:(1,2) 
>  ANDROID   V:(1,2)  C:(3,1) 
>  PRECIOUSLY   V:(1,3,1)  C:(2,1,2) 
>  EXCEEDING   V:(1,2,1)  C:(2,1,2)

Not Variadic:

> NIGHTMARE   V:(**1,1,1**)  C:(1,4,1) 
>  RESPONSIBLE  V:(**1,1,1,1**)  C:(**1,2,2,2**) 
>  APPLE   V:(**1,1**)  C:(3) 
>  VALUABLY  V:(1,2,1)  C:(**1,1,2**)

Note:

> This assumes the 'Y' in Daydream is treated as a consonant

Answer (score 3):

Variadic words:

> Have groups of 1..n vowels and 1..n consonants, where n is at least 2.

Whereas non-variadic words:

> Skips some value for the numbers of vowels or consonants, or doesn't reach 2.

Examples!

> **Headstock** is variadic:
>  Vowels: 'o', 'ea'.
>  Consonants: 'h', 'ck', 'dst'.
>
>  **Daydream** is variadic:
>  Vowels: 'a', 'ea'. (Note we don't count Y as a vowel here)
>  Consonants: 'd', 'dr'. (Note we don't count Y as a consonant here)
>
>  **Responsible** is non-variadic:
>  Vowels: 'e'. (Doesn't reach 2)
>  Consonants: 'r', 'sp'.
>
>  **Fretboard** is non-variadic:
>  Vowels: 'e', 'oa'.
>  Consonants: 'fr'. (1 is skipped)
>
>  **Nightmare** is non-variadic:
>  Vowels: 'i'. (Doesn't reach 2)
>  Consonants: 'n', 'ghtm'. (2 and 3 are skipped)

Comment: This is really thinking in the right direction. You should be counting the Y as either a consonant or a vowel, however (but not both!).

Comment: Darn! Also, I now see that 'valuably' would be variadic under my rules.

Answer (score 1):

All Variadic words have:

> Two vowels right next to each other

Example:

> Daydr**ea**m 
>  L**ia**ble 
>  Andr**oi**d 
>  Ind**ia**n 
>  Br**ai**nstorm 
>  Stym**ie** 
>  Prec**iou**sly 
>  Centr**io**le 
>  H**ea**dstock 
>  Bass**oo**n 
>  Peng**ui**n 
>  Farb**au**ti 
>  Exc**ee**ding 
>  Str**ea**king

Comment: Note that `Fretboard`, `Valuably`, and `Vacuole` are not Variadic.

Comment: @erdekhayser Shoot, am I on the right track though?

Comment: You're starting to think about it the right way. If this is the first step, you have about 3 or 4 more to go. But your observation definitely has to do with the answer.

Comment: @erdekhayser I guess I'll have another look at it tommorrow

Comment: I'm going to add this at a later point, but "Thirst" is also Variadic.

Comment: Is it important whether or not you consider 'y' a vowel?

Comment: @Joe Y is sometimes a vowel, sometimes a consonant depending on the word, which is important to how you solve the puzzle.